# How to send data from Android Service to its AIDL stub

Tags: android, bluetooth, broadcastreceiver, android-service, android-broadcast

I am developing a application to initiate the Bluetooth device application.

I have a service called `MyService`.
I have stub `MyServiceImpl` to handle the AIDL interface which will be called from outside.
I have broadcastreceiver to get the "`ACTION_BOND_STATE_CHANGED`".

My requirement is whenever device is connected(i.e `device?.bondState == BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED`, I need to send deviceinfo from Broadcast receiver to `MyServiceImpl` stub.
The Reason - AIDL interface is already handled there, once the aidl is called, new class will be created from there. For that new class `MyServiceImpl` is needed. In addition, response to that interface call is sent through callbacks is also handled there.

The code is below. Can someone help me to send the device information from Broadcastreceiver to the Service stub Implementation?

```
class MyService : Service() {

    override fun onBind(intent: Intent): IBinder {
        return binder
    }

    override fun onUnbind(intent: Intent?): Boolean {
        return super.onUnbind(intent)
    }

    override fun onCreate() {
       binder = MyServiceImpl()
       filterNewDevices()
    }

    private fun filterNewDevices() {
        val filter = IntentFilter()
        filter.addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_BOND_STATE_CHANGED)
        registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiverBond, filter)
    }

    private val mBroadcastReceiverBond: BroadcastReceiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {

        override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent) {
            if (intent.action == BluetoothDevice.ACTION_BOND_STATE_CHANGED) {
                val device = intent.getParcelableExtra<BluetoothDevice>(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE)

                if (device?.bondState == BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED) {
                    //HERE I NEED TO SEND THE device TO 
                }

                if (device?.bondState == BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDING) {
                }

                if (device?.bondState == BluetoothDevice.BOND_NONE) {
                }
            }
        }
    }

    class MyServiceImpl : IBluetoothConnection.Stub(), IBinder {

        private lateinit var  btConnection: BTConnection

        override fun registerUuid(name : String?, uuid : String?, connectionId : Int, btDevice : BluetoothDevice?) {
                btConnection = BTConnection(this)
                btConnection.initialize(name!!, UUID.fromString(uuid), connectionId, btDevice)
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Create a method in `MyServiceImpl` that takes the `device` as a parameter. In your `BroadcastReceiver` call the method on `binder` to pass the device to the service implementation.

Comment: Thank you @DavidWasser - it works

Comment: Super. I created an answer. You can accept the answer if it was useful to you by clicking on the green checkmark next to the answer. This will also remove this question from the list of open questions. Glad you were able to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a method in `MyServiceImpl` that takes the device as a parameter. In your `BroadcastReceiver` call the method on `binder` to pass the device to the service implementation.